# GraphQl says "bad token" when connecting to Artifactory endpoint

Tags: graphql, artifactory

I'm trying got make some request as the documentation

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <Your Token>" -XPOST http://<server:port>/metadata/api/v1/query -d '{"query":"..." }'
```

Also directly in http://artifactory.com:PORT/metadata/api/v1/query/graphiql.
I previously generated my access token as admin in Jfrog but each time I send a request I get a "bad token" message. Should I use a special TOKEN?

Comment: Hi, could you please provide more information? are you using the Cloud version? Onprem version? if on-prem, can you provide the version you are using?

Answer (score -1):

i could get this working like that:

```
curl -X POST "https://<MYCOMPANY>.jfrog.io/metadata/api/v1/query" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <MY_TOKEN>" \
-d '{
  "query": "query ($filter: PackageFilter!, $first: Int, $orderBy: PackageOrder) { packages (filter: $filter, first: $first, orderBy: $orderBy) { edges { node { id, name, created, modified, versionsCount, description, latestVersion, packageType, stats { downloads, followers }, licenses { name, source }, tags, vulnerabilities { critical, high, medium, low, info, unknown, skipped } } }, pageInfo { hasNextPage, endCursor } } }",
  "variables": {
    "filter": {
      "name": "*"
    },
    "first": 100,
    "orderBy": {
      "field": "NAME",
      "direction": "ASC"
    }
  }
}'
```

can you try the above command and check if it works for you? (change the values of the company and token of course)